# Missing render preview. No automatic re-render when changes are made, etc

Tags: rendering

- Other than installing Node Wrangler, I haven't made any changes to user prefs since install.
- I do have "Update Automatically" checked.
- My materials preview, however, *is* updating when I make changes to it.

edit: wording improved

Comment: there is an option for pausing all viewport preview rendering , check if it isn't enabled.

Comment: I'm talking about F12 rendering, not viewport rendering. The issue is the render result only updates when I manually hit F12. In an installation I had on my old machine, my render result would update automatically if I made changes. Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: To clarify, I keep a window dragged open so I can see my render result. I tend to do small sprites, so my render constantly updating is fairly practical per my needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the "update automatically" option under view menu of UV/image editor, which is also used to keep rendering results, this:

[image]

which says "update other affected window spaces automatically to reflect changes during interactive operations such as transform"

Imho that has nothing to do with re-rendering automatically. That, for sure, acts on UV editing: if enabled, e.g., other 3D views in "textured" mode are updated automatically **while** you're still transforming your UV map in that editor. Without it enabled, the update happen only **after** you commit the UV editing. It sort enables a realtime results preview **while** editing UV.

To get something similar to what you describe, you could get that effect using another Blender editor option:

instead of using this windows setup:

[image]

you could use "area duplication" options like:

[image]

obtaining a small separate window that you can set as "rendered" viewport shading (works both in Internal and Cycles, nowadays):

[image]

Now, in this way every little change in your objects is immediately reflected (re-rendered) in the small window. Hth.

Comment: Turns out I had a second 3d viewport open with viewport rendering enabled. Wouldn't have realized it had you not taken the time to troubleshoot such a weird problem. Thanks.